# Stuck in call back hell in node js

Tags: javascript, node.js, callback

I am trying to modify this  node library to add a extra exists method

This is the link to the library - https://github.com/mikolalysenko/interval-tree-1d/blob/master/interval-tree.js

**This is what i have created**

```
proto.queryPointExists = function(x, cb) {
    if(x < this.mid) {
      if(this.left) {
        var r = this.left.queryPointExists(x, cb)
        if(r) { return r }
      }
      return reportLeftRangeExists(this.leftPoints, x, cb)
    } else if(x > this.mid) {
      if(this.right) {
        var r = this.right.queryPointExists(x, cb)
        if(r) { return r }
      }
      //console.log(reportRightRangeExists(this.rightPoints, x, cb));
      return reportRightRangeExists(this.rightPoints, x, cb)
    } else {
      return reportRangeExists(this.leftPoints, cb)
    }
  }

  function reportLeftRangeExists(arr, hi, cb) {
    for(var i=0; i<arr.length && arr[i][0] <= hi; ++i) {
      var r = cb(arr[i])
      if(r) { return r }
    }
  }

  function reportRightRangeExists(arr, lo, cb) {  
    for(var i=arr.length-1; i>=0 ; --i) {
      if(arr[i][1] >= lo){
        var r = cb(arr[i])
        if(r) { return r }
      } else {
        return false;
      } 
    }
  }

  function reportRangeExists(arr, cb) {
    for(var i=0; i<arr.length; ++i) {
      var r = cb(arr[i])
      if(r) { return r }
    }
  }

tproto.queryPointExists = function(p, cb) {
    console.log("Here");
    if(this.root) {
      //console.log(this.root.queryPointExists(p, cb)+"ss");  
      return this.root.queryPointExists(p, cb);
    }
  }
```

The problem is the call backs are wind pretty tight what i want to achieve is that if any interval matches the query point it should return true and exit out immediately . but due to insane recursive callback i am stuck and it never reaches the top .

Please help

Comment: What do you need callbacks for? All your functions appear to be synchronous.

Comment: @Bergi but if you check the code it is a visitor pattern if the node or internal is not there it dosent return values, i want to just check if node is not there return a false

Comment: I am trying to add a extra method to this lib which checks that  node exists between intervals or not if exists return true else false